# How to access photo Gallery of mobile using j2me code

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, photo-gallery

I am making an application in which I will change wallpaper of the mobile screen, but I have no idea how it is possible through j2me.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the screen wallpaper using with Java ME. unfortunately its not currently possible.

For accessing photo's, look on the sample application (PDAPDemo application) on installed sun java toolkit workspace under *Apps folder* or under the NetBeans Java ME sample applications.

Answer (score 0):

In mobile device you can access memory card using `E:` in your path.

you can also try,

`String initDir = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.photos");`